# Performance issue: change Mysql row format from fixed to dynamic

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a Mysql table with 1.28 billion rows. The structure of the table is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE `wx_week_score` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `r1` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `r2` char(10) NOT NULL,
    `r3` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `r4` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `r5` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `r6` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `r7` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1281789 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

Recently I have tried to change the row format to `dynamic`, but I encountered a problem: the usage of CPU is very high and almost full.

I have many update operations in my programs, and I guess these operations exhaust the CPU resource, maybe.

Can someone give me explanations? Thanks.

Comment: Questions about MySQL performance should include de queries.. And EXPLAiN query if your MySQL version supports EXPLAIN on UPDATE queries

Comment: @RaymondNijlandI'm using Mysql 5.1, and there is no EXPLAIN command. I'm sorry I don't know how to give more information.

Comment: Oeps I typed the dutch word "de" I mean "the" @FrankerZ

Comment: @FishWu You probably should consider upgrading.

Comment: There should be a EXPLAIN command in MySQL 5.1.. But MySQL 5.1 will only support EXPLAIN on SELECT qeuries.. you can start by posting the update queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chewed up the CPU during the conversion to `DYNAMIC`, so what?  It is a one-time task.

If `SELECTs` are chewing up the CPU now, let's see them.  I see only one index, so I would expect lots of full table scans.  If you have enough RAM to cache the table (abouit 40GB), then that would explain the high CPU, but not explain why you did not see it with `FIXED`.

If that is truly the `CREATE TABLE` before and after the conversion to `DYNAMIC`, I suspect there is *no* difference in performance.  If you also changed `CHAR(10)` to `VARCHAR(10)`, I would not expect more than a trivial difference in performance.

Do you really need `INT`?  If you change one `INT` to `TINYINT`, that would save about 4GB of disk space.  And make the table more cacheable.

The `UPDATE` command can be impacted a lot - between `FIXED` and `DYNAMIC`.

For `FIXED`, the row is changed "in place".  The row is fetched, modified, then stored.

For `DYNAMIC`, the same will happen if the resulting row is no bigger than the original.  If, instead, it grows (due to a longer string in a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` column), the overflow needs to be put somewhere else.  This is done by chaining together pieces of the record, filling in empty spots in the data.

So,... Since you said the the CPU, not the I/O, went up, I deduce

- you have enough RAM for the table
- you did switch to `VARCHAR`
- the updates are often lengthening the lone 10-character string.

If I deduced correctly, then

- You have probably found a (rare) use case where `FIXED` is better than `DYNAMIC`.
- Because of linking pieces of records together, the table may actually be bigger than before, and continue to grow even if no `INSERTs` are done.

You really should switch to InnoDB and `VARCHAR`; virtually everything I mentioned is irrelevant in InnoDB.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I will consider changing the MyISAM engine to InnoDB.